# Sharing photos stopped working in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

Sometime this week, sharing photos or albums with a link stopped working for me. Happened alongside the slight UI update, I think. Does anyone else have this problem?

Steps to reproduce (from the browser):

1. Create a new album and put pictures in it or choose a single picture.
2. Create a sharing link.
3. Open the sharing link in another browser or in a new private window.
4. The "album" is empty.
5. The album is not empty if you open the link when signed in to your account.

I found no mentions of this issue anywhere and some friends also have the same issues. Links generated a couple of weeks ago, which worked last weekend, also don't work now.

Cross-link: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlephotos/comments/54aqx3/sharing_photos_stopped_working/) reddit post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a real issue with the service. In [this thread in the Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/2Kt-S6xRrQo), several people complain about this very thing, then a "Top Contributor" chimes in with:

> Hi all, thanks for your reports, I've passed them to the Google Photos team. I'm going to mark this as the best answer so it gets highlighted in the discussion and new users can see it. I'll post any updates here.

The (current) final message in the thread is from 6:07 AM Eastern on 25-September, and it's someone reporting that it's working again.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include information from the link to make the answer self-contained.